# mysql: how to outfile csv - limit x number of rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have some queries like this

```
(SELECT 'title', 'created_at', 'modified_at')
UNION
(select title, created_at, modified_at from table1 order by created_at
INTO OUTFILE 'result.csv'
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n');
```

and the the result is more than 10000 rows.

Is there a way to split this into multiple files?
I would like to limit the number of rows.

I know that I can do something like this:

```
select * from table1 limit 0, 1000 into outfile result1.csv
select * from table1 limit 1000, 1000 into outfile result2.csv
select * from table1 limit 2000, 1000 into outfile result3.csv
...
```

since there's more than 10000 rows, I am wondering if I can use some kind of loop.

Any advice and help will be greatly appreciated!

**::EDIT::**

I wrote repeat procedure but it gives me a syntax error.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `reapeatloop`()
BEGIN
declare x int;
declare filename varchar(255);
declare lowlimit int;
SET x = 0;
REPEAT
  set lowlimit = x*1000;
  (select * from table1 limit lowlimit, 1000
   INTO OUTFILE concat('post',x,'.csv')
   CHARACTER SET utf8
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES 
   TERMINATED BY '\r\n');
   SET x = x + 1;
UNTIL x > 19 END REPEAT;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Inside this query, I used local variable to define csv and limit value and this gives syntax error. can anyone see what's wrong with this query?
as soon as I change this variable to some number, or string, it creates procedure successfully.

Comment: couldn't you just make a larger range by limiting 0, 10000 then 10001, 20000, etc? then amalgamate them into one. if that is not feasible, then I can see the need for the loop.

Comment: when you use `limit`, to maintain integrity, try to use `order by` on a column with order (for example of id or timestamp). Then use `mysql LOOP`.

Comment: @majidhajibaba hi, thanks for the response and pointing out `order by`. I have added how I wrote repeat procedure to my original post, could you please look at it?

Comment: @Mech oh, I was requested to limit it by 1000..! there's another person who use this exported csv file and said it's too big to work with XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some mistake in your procedure. Specially check the [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html).
Be careful about the position of `FROM`.
In your case try this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE reapeatloop;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `reapeatloop`()
BEGIN
declare x int;
declare filename varchar(255);
declare lowlimit int;
SET x = 0;
REPEAT
  set lowlimit = x*1000;  
  SET @fullOutputPath := CONCAT('"D:/post',x,'.csv"');
  set @q1 := concat("select * INTO OUTFILE ", @fullOutputPath, 
    " CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
   from table1 limit ", lowlimit, ",1000");
    
    select @q1;
    
    prepare s1 from @q1;
    execute s1;deallocate prepare s1;
    
    SET x = x + 1;
    
UNTIL x > 19 END REPEAT;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```